# Unpacking a list into multiple sub lists of different sizes

Tags: python

I have a list say:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I want to unpack it into three lists such that:

```
list1 = [1, 2]
list2 = [3, 4, 5]
list3 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I can do it using slicing as:

```
list1 = my_list[0 : 2]
list2 = my_list[2 : 5]
list3 = my_list[5 : 10]
```

But I want to know if there exists a more elegant way to unpack original list into these 3 sub-lists directly.

Comment: `list1,list2,list3 = my_list[0 : 2],my_list[2 : 5],my_list[5 : 10]`?

Comment: What do you mean by more elegant way ? This is already a good solution.

Comment: @DeepakTripathi

I wanted to ask for solution as if we have for this case 
x , y , *z = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5]
so this will print : x = 1 , y = 2 , z = [3 , 4 , 5]
Is there some way we can do to for multiple sub lists too ,
since i tried using multiple starred expressions like *x , *y
but that doesn't work. I thought using *x , *y = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4]
could have unpacked sub lists of equal size like [1 , 2] and [3 , 4]

Comment: There really isn't anything simpler than what you current have.

Comment: I've closed your question under an existing one that covers the same sort of task. To be explicit, what you want is `list1, list2, list3 = partition(my_list, [2, 5])` (using the [top answer](/a/1198876/4518341)). LMK if you have any questions though. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.